# Linuxサーバーのサービスログ確認の良い方法は？

Tags: linux

Linuxサーバー上において，nginx, php-fpm, mysqldといったサービスを起動しています．
これらのサービスのログファイルを簡単に確認できるソフトウェアはあるでしょうか？

現状では不具合がある度に `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` のようにコマンドを打って確認しており，非常に効率が悪く感じます．

Comment: どういうふうに、なってほしいのでしょうか？単に、root権限取得、端末ソフトの起動、tailコマンドの打ち込みを省略したいだけなら、自分用のshell scriptを書いて、chown;chmod +sして、起動するようにし、それぞれのlog file対象に複数走らせて、端末表示させて、眺めていれば、いいだけですが。

Answer (score 2):

エラーを見つけたいとのことですので、`tail -f`では垂れ流しになってしまい、難しいのではないかと思います。商用のアプリは山ほどありますが、無料でオープンソースであればELKスタック (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana)が人気です。ログの収集からエラー検出条件の設定、グラフの描画まで簡単にできます。

それぞれの役割は

1. LogstashはETL(データの収集、書式変換、格納）
2. Elasticsearchは検索に特化したデータベース
3. Kibanaはユーザーインターフェース

インストール手順は[こちら](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04)。

応用編としては、エラーが起きた時のスタックトレースの文字列のハッシュをLogstashで計算して、IDとして格納します。同じIDの出現頻度を数えれば、頻出エラーのバグフィックスを先にやるということもできるし、逆にレア物から修正して大問題になるのを未然に防ぐということもできそうです。

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f`なのでリアルタイムのログが見たいという前提で回答します。

これを実現する他のソフトウェアというのはなかなかありません。普通は表示の操作をしたタイミングまでのログまででしょう(`cat`や`-f`なしの`tail`相当)。確認してませんが、PleskやHDE Controllerのような商用のサーバ管理ソフトウェアであればできるかもしれません。

`sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`と打つのが大変、ということであれば、aliasを設定してはいかがでしょう。.bashrcに

```
alias tf='sudo tail -f'
```

と書いておけば、`tf /var/log/...`で`sudo tail -f /var/log/...`が実行できます。いっそのことファイル名まで含めたaliasにしてもよいでしょう。

また、ログを確認する専用のユーザを作って、.bashrcに

`sudo tail -f ...`

を書いてもいいかもしれません。ログインしたら勝手にログが表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

他の方もおっしゃっているように、どうなれば便利と感じるかを示して頂ければより具体的な回答ができると思われます。

例えばログファイルが分散しているのが不便ということであれば、nginx、php-fpm、mysqldいずれもsyslog出力に対応していますので、syslogサーバを立ててそこに集中して飛ばせば、ログの確認は1か所で済みますね。また、ログに特定の文字列が出力された際にメール等のアラートを上げたいということであれば、Zabbixなどの監視ソフトでログファイル監視をすることも可能です。